# "No emit error" with dynamic import of components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm new to the UX world so please ask me for any more information needed to answer this question.

I've a React-Redux-Typescript project. I'm trying to leverage dynamic import of modules based on the paths given in a config file. This is the code for dynamic import:

```
 import(`../${this.app.appPath}`).then(component => {
    this.component = component.default;
  });
```

Here this.app.appPath will be path to the landing component for the app. Eg; Test/App

I'm having an issue where this piece of code causes the error with typings file:
[image]

My tsconfig has configuration as this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "diagnostics": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES2018" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "esnext" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "scripthost",
      "es2018",
      "es2018.promise",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "jsx": "react" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
    "sourceMap": true /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */,
    "outDir": "./.out/" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "ScriptsApp/@Types"]
  },
  "include": ["./ScriptsApp/**/*.tsx", "./ScriptsApp/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./ScriptsApp/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

And my folder structure is this:

[image]

So I think the d.ts files should not be compiled. But the dynamic import is causing them to compile as per my understanding; that's what is causing the *no emit error*

My webpack config is as follows for .ts files:

```
  {
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    exclude: /\.(\.d\.ts)$/,
    loader: "ts-loader",
    options: {
      logLevel: "info",
      silent: false,
      logInfoToStdOut: true
    }
  }
```

Here also I'm excluding the .d.ts files, not sure why they are being compiled. As soon as I remove the code for dynamic import, the error goes away. Please help, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue but that exclude pattern is not correct.  It would only match `..d.ts` and not `foo.d.ts`https://regex101.com/r/Nv8dti/1

Comment: Also, why not put your custom apps up a directory (at the same level as `node_modules`) and save yourself from needing the exclude pattern at all.

Comment: @Pace I cannot change the directory structure..